# random and certainty in python?

Tags: python, random

I have a simple script, say to print an string. Now I would like to run this script 100 times, I would like to make sure the string would be printed at least 1 time, but not more than 3 times. Statistically, I would like this string to be printed for 1% ~ 3% times of totally running times.

May I know how can I make it in Python?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is a great example of what I call a "gimme-teh-codez" question. The question states what the program should do, but shows no effort whatsoever on the user's part to develop the program for themselves. Just "hey, I want it to do this, now gimme teh codez". Occasionally, if the problem is interesting, this will work; but most of the time, it will get downvoted and closed, just like this one did. It's clear that you're literate in English, so please go and read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you post again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from random import randint
from pickle import dump, load
from os.path import isfile

if isfile('state.bin'):
    with open('state.bin', 'rb') as fh:
        state = load(fh)
else:
    state = {'counter' : 0, 'iterations' : 1}

if state['counter'] == 0 and state['iterations'] == 100:
    print('a string*')
else:
    if randint(0, 100) < 3 and state['counter'] < 3:
        print('a string*')
        state['counter'] += 1
state['iterations'] += 1

with open('state.bin', 'wb') as fh:
    dump(state, fh)
```

Now run this script a 100 times, and statistically this should only print `a string` 1-3% of the time. It also keeps track of how many iterations you've done and if the ammount is less than 1 or more than 3 and will act accordingly.

Comment: That could print more than 3 times.  It could print 0 times.  The requirement was "at least 1 time, but not more than 3 times."

Comment: @MarkTolonen True, i'll work on that just as the question should be worked on : )

Comment: @MarkTolonen Fixed. I must admit my silly answer to a vague question was perhaps not as amusing as I thought. I hope this is better.

Comment: @Torxed, I am thinking the same solution, but as Mark said, it may print 0 times, which is unacceptable, though 5 times is good for me to accept. is there any possibility to run it at least once? There is no external file can be saved otherwise I will use it for a counter.

Comment: @CoeusWang I added a external "state" file that keeps track if you've printed 0 times on the last iteration, or if you're trying to print more than 3 times.